# Splitting a laptop into 2 consoles

Tags: linux, console, tty

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, Dell Latitude E4200.

It sometimes lands in a docking station with a set of peripheral devices:

- screen
- keyboard
- mouse
- sometimes some USB drives, etc (as an aside)

The startup routine is standard, ie. 7 tty's with GUI on tty 7.

What I want is to split the docking configuration, so that:

- the docking station with its peripherals forms one console
- the laptop keyboard + touchpad + screen are a separate one.

(The docking station has its own audio line, but let's skip audio for simplicity.)

The external console would carry on with the standard GUI session on tty 7, while the laptop console would start with tty 1, both being able to switch around all 7 tty's.

The target is to have two scripts. One turning the split on, the second one canceling it. No settings should be affected permanently. In case something goes wrong, at the next boot-up the system should start up like so far.

I have knowledge about devices and tty's, but not this deep. What's the right place to apply the rebinds and why?